# What's wrong with my questions, and how can I improve them?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions, deleted-questions, post-ban

Coming from [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), as you can guess, I am actually question banned.

I have read plenty of meta topics about being question banned and the only way out seems to be "Improve your questions"... Fine, I went through all my actual questions, and besides deleting a [seemingly useless question that was about to be deleted automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436558/obtain-minwidth-of-uniformgrids-childs) and a few details on other questions, I don't really think there's a lot for me to do to make my questions better (which is surely wrong since I'm question banned).

I suspect that my deleted questions (from most to least downvotes : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52465598/10352740), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64446422/10352740), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62998000/10352740), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60074277/10352740), [5 (undeleted and edited but deleted again by Community user)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66337518/10352740), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55695656/10352740), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59411353/how-to-set-default-value-for-mockbehaviour-using-moq), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64369256/10352740), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60436558/10352740), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60223537/10352740), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60168769/10352740), [12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60634382/10352740)) are those that weigh the most in my ban and hence are the ones to edit, but as far as I can remember, me deleting these questions was most of the time because, according to comments and/or downvotes, they were not good, and it was simply me acknowledging that they aren't meant to stay on Stack Overflow, even after being edited.

Are those questions going to be a burden forever or is there anything I can do about it? What can I do to make my questions better in order to ask my new question (and not get banned again since I'm not considered a good asker)?

Comment: The deleted question you linked, i don't see anything particularly wrong with it, all it needs is an edit to bump it back to the front page. Keep in mind, on the list of questions, the first bit of your question is displayed as a preview... it's often a good idea to be descriptive there rather than just saying "Using the following XAML"

Comment: You likely have a significant amount of deleted questions with downvotes, since your non-deleted ones net you a positive score with no closed questions. I'd generally advise modflagging one of your own questions to ask if a mod can provide you with a list of questions you've deleted so you can improve and undelete them, but since you already asked here it's probably better to wait and see if one happens to stumble in to this question. As for the ones that aren't deleted, they mostly look fine to me as well, but they aren't your problem.

Comment: Among the questions that have been deleted that I have found, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64446422/textbox-borderbrushs-value-locked-after-being-assigned-to-dynamicresource) in particular doesn't look bad to me

Comment: That deleted question needs proper steps to setup a fresh project to get it in a state that becomes clear. Basically what you now added at the end needs to go near the start of the question. I assume VS2019? .Net Core/.Net framework/ doesn't matter?  Make the edits then flag for a mod to have that question undeleted AND the comments cleaned, once undeleted make one extra edit so it gets bumped on the active tab for c# and wpf followers. Isn't there a tag missing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mahapps.metro ?

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/66337518) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/64446422) [3](//stackoverflow.com/q/64369256) [4](//stackoverflow.com/q/62998000) [5](//stackoverflow.com/q/60436558) [6](//stackoverflow.com/q/60223537) [7](//stackoverflow.com/q/60168769) [8](//stackoverflow.com/q/60074277) [9](//stackoverflow.com/q/52465598)

Comment: Apologies for the delay @nalka

Comment: Perhaps edit them one by one to see if you can get them into shape? Don't do them all at once. And focus on answering posts instead of asking Questions?

Comment: @Scratte I do answer more than ask (nearly twice more answers than questions). Yes I plan on editing one by one those that I still find useful (among the deleted ones) but those are rare cases, most of the others are either not suitable for SO (which is why I deleted them) or now irrelevant

Comment: The older ones definitely look like you needed to read the guidance for providing a [MRE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but I doubt they are salvageable. #2 looks like it could be resurrected if you added the code you failed to include even after being asked. #3 is a duplicate, so could probably relatively safely be undeleted without any further noise (though it's always possible that reopening it will attract downvotes from people who don't like duplicates; not my field of expertise so I don't know how obvious it is). #4 should probably be closed, so undeleting it seems futile. (Cont.)

Comment: #5 was deleted by Community for inactivity, so probably not worth reopening, though again if you could provide an MRE, perhaps it could be revived. #6 looks vaguely too broad / opinion-based / recommendation-oriented, so probably abandon it. #7 and #8 look like perhaps they could be salvaged, perhaps with some additional details. #9 and #10 were again deleted by Community.

Comment: Try fixing the least downvoted ones first. Positive score matters. Easy to go from 0 to 1 rather than -5 to 1.

Comment: Are you still question banned?

Comment: @TheMaster At the moment, I can ask a question. I'm not checking really often though, and I may be wrong but I think I have been unbanned when I reached 1000 rep

Comment: @nalka I see. Thanks for the info.